# Runtime Error: Cant start new thread while only running 4 threads at once

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

[Output Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2W0U.png)

In my code I call threads so I can speed up the loop time. My issues is that after a couple hours of the bot running i get the error above. I've tried limited threads to a maxium of 4 before using threading.active_count() > 1 but it still returns an exception. I even close all other applications to increase my computer performace. I've never had this issues before... Below is the threads my bot calls (11 total exactly like this)

Couple of things:

1. It only breaks after about 4-6 hours
2. I've notice twice it breaks on the about 160th loop (Although im not for sure this is consistent)
3. My computer/internet is more than powerful enough to be able to run this (It can run cyberpunk 2077 just fine)
4. There are 100 Ids in _MessageIds
5. I would prevent more than 3 threads from being active with the following code:
   `while threading.active_count() > 1:  time.sleep(0.2)`
6. I use queues in my Threads to get the needed embeds

```
def No_Listings_output():
    try:
        _MessageIds = MessageIds.get("Premium_No_Listings")
        MessageAmounts = math.ceil(No_Listings_queue.qsize() / 10)
        if len(_MessageIds) < MessageAmounts:
            print(
                f"No_Listings MessageIds needs {MessageAmounts-len(_MessageIds)} more ids"
            )
        for Id in _MessageIds:
            if not No_Listings_queue.empty():
                embed_list = []
                for i in range(10):
                    if not No_Listings_queue.empty():
                        embed_list.append(No_Listings_queue.get())
                if len(embed_list) > 0:
                    No_Listings_discord_webhook.edit_message(
                        message_id=Id, content="", embeds=embed_list
                    )
            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 0, 0),
                    description="",
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="",
                    value="Nothing to see here...",
                    inline=False,
                )
                No_Listings_discord_webhook.edit_message(
                    message_id=Id, content="", embed=embed
                )
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except:
        pass




Thread(target=Premium_All_output, name="Premium_All").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Special_All_output, name="Special_All").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Basic_All_output, name="Basic_All").start()
while threading.active_count() > 1:
    time.sleep(0.2)
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=No_Listings_output, name="No_Listings").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=No_collection_output, name="No_collection").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Quick_output, name="Quick").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Special_Major_output, name="Special_Major").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
while threading.active_count() > 1:
    time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Premium_Major_output, name="Premium_Major").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Basic_Forge_output, name="Basic_Forge").start()

time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Special_Forge_output, name="Special_Forge").start()
time.sleep(0.2)
Thread(target=Premium_Forge_output, name="Premium_Forge").start()

while threading.active_count() > 1:
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

2 hours after post - EDIT: Is it potentially because I forgot to use .task_done() and .join() for my queues so my Threads and never closing? But if that is true, then when do my while loops eventually pass??

Comment: Is it potentially because I forgot to use .task_done() and .join() for my queues so my Threads and never closing? But if that is true, then when do my while loops eventually pass??